# LVDS signals having different ground reference with coupling capacitor

Tags: lvds

I'm simulating a LVDS driver connected to a LVDS receiver with a 100nF series coupling capacitor in between the +ve and -ve signal lines using the respective IBIS model of the same buffer. (DS25BR100 from TI)

[image]

Below is the waveform of the simulation

[image]

Right after i remove the coupling capacitor, the waveforms are back to the correcct differential pattern.

[image]

Would like to ask why and how can I enable the waveform to have the same differential pattern while having the coupling capacitor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide bias to the LVDS receiver as shown here (from [TI app note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scaa059c/scaa059c.pdf)).

Normally it would come from the transmitter but you have removed any DC coupling with the capacitors.

[image: LVDS using AC coupling]

Comment: Yes, I get your point but my concern was that even with bias provided at the receiver, the waveform in image 1 remains. I was expecting it to be bias and have the waveform show in image 2 as well.

Comment: But your scope plot shows the voltage around zero with the caps - it doesn't show any bias. I agree it is unexpected for both lines o have a different average voltage. Can you show the circuit of the simulation?

Comment: Yeah I have upload the picture of the circuit. No bias is provided, but when bias is provided the same waveform is observed with an offset only. The receiver is internally terminated with 100 ohm.

Comment: Are you sure it has an internal terminator?  If you have a DC voltage between the bins that would put current through the terminator but where would it come from?  I suspect there is no internal terminator.  Try putting one externally.

Comment: @KevinWhite DS25BR100 definitely has a termination resistor built in.

Comment: Did you ever get to a conclusion here? Could it be that the DS25BR100 is biasing the lines in that way?